# JTable not filled

Tags: java, swing

I have got JTable with datas from DataBase. Once the table is filled but somotimes (totally random) not. Connection with DB is correct. I haven't got any idea why in one situation table is filled and in other not. there is absolutely no rule.

Model class:

```
public class MaterialModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
  public List<Material> materials = new ArrayList<Material>();
  String[] columns = {"ID_Material", "Nazwa"};

public int getRowCount() {
    return this.materials.size();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return columns.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int col){
    return columns[col];
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Material material = materials.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex)
    {
        case 0: return material.id;
        case 1: return material.name;
    }
    return null;
}

public void setListMaterials(List<Material> listMaterials){
    this.materials = listMaterials;
}

public void reset(){
    this.materials.clear();
}
}
```

Form class:

```
public class Form extends JFrame{

private JTable materialTable;
MaterialDAO materialDAO;
public MaterialModel materialModel;

public Form() throws SQLException {
    super("Magazyn");
    setContentPane(mainPane);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,500);
    this.initComponets();
    materialDAO = new MaterialDaoImpl();
    materialTable.setModel(new MaterialModel());
    this.fillTable();
}

public void fillTable() throws SQLException {

    this.materialTable.repaint();
    materialModel = (MaterialModel) this.materialTable.getModel();
    materialModel.reset();
    materialModel.setListMaterials(materialDAO.getAllMaterials());
}


}
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I think that at this stage you need to do some more debugging, perhaps best done by logging, and this will likely give you more information and help than we can provide.

Answer (score 0):

As i see there is no SQL query, check if you are executing a sql query, i don't know if you are using Hibernate or something other, try to put the part of executing sql query, by this way we can see the error you did.

Comment: Connect with DB jest correct. I have connection and executing query in other class. I tested it, write datas in console. I have problem with filling table.

Comment: you have to add your data to model, as following  : YourTableModel.setDataVector(your_Data_Vector, the_Header);